# Is the way of determining my angle of vector wrong or am I using the wrong formula for calculating magnitude of resultant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, kinematics, vectors, velocity

i) Two balls A and B are simultaneously projected from top of building at 10m/s upward and 20m/s downward. Find distance between them after 3s? (Answer: 90m)

There are two magnitude of resultant formula:
$$ 
First: R = |\vec{A} + \vec{B}|  = \sqrt{(A^2 + B^2 + 2ABCos\theta)}
;R = |\vec{A} - \vec{B}|  = \sqrt{(A^2 + B^2 + 2A(-B)Cos\theta)}
$$
$$ 
Second: R = |\vec{A} + \vec{B}|  = \sqrt{(|A^2| + |B^2| + 2|A||B|Cos\theta)}
;R = |\vec{A} - \vec{B}|  = \sqrt{(|A^2| + |B^2| + 2|A||(-B)|Cos\theta)}
$$
I think the first formula is right, so I will be solving the questions using first formula.
Now for angle, opposite parallel vector angle is 180 and same side parallel vector is 0 degree.

###### Initial solution for i):

A = 10m/s, B = 20m/s, t = 3s, angle = 180(180 degrees as they are opposite parallel vectors) but right answer either comes from angle = 0 degree or using different formula.
Lets assume angle is 180 as they are opposite parallel vectors. So, answer by this method is wrong.
So, $$ R = |\vec{A} + \vec{B}|  = \sqrt{(A^2 + B^2 + 2ABCos\theta)} = \sqrt{(10^2+20^2+2*10*20*Cos180)} = \sqrt{(100+400+400*-1)} = \sqrt{100} = 10m/s $$
$$ R.V = \frac{d}{t} => d = RV*t = 10*3 = 30m $$

###### Potential correct solution for i):

A = 10m/s, B = 20m/s, t = 3s, angle = 0 degree
So, $$ R = |\vec{A} + \vec{B}|  = \sqrt{(A^2 + B^2 + 2ABCos\theta)} = \sqrt{(10^2+20^2+2*10*20*Cos0)} = \sqrt{(100+400+400*1)} = \sqrt{900} = 30m/s $$
$$ R.V = \frac{d}{t} => d = RV*t = 30*3 = 90m $$

###### Potential correct solution for i):

A = 10m/s, B = 20m/s, t = 3s, angle = 180 degree but using $$ R = |\vec{A} - \vec{B}| = \sqrt{(A^2 + B^2 + 2A(-B)Cos\theta)} $$
So, $$ R = |\vec{A} - \vec{B}|  = \sqrt{(A^2 + B^2 - 2ABCos\theta)} = \sqrt{(10^2+20^2-2*10*20*Cos180)} = \sqrt{(100+400-400*-1)} = \sqrt{500+400} = 30m/s $$
$$ R.V = \frac{d}{t} => d = RV*t = 30*3 = 90m $$

This means either my formula is wrong or my assumed angle is wrong. I know that when two vectors are moving away from each other, in straight line their velocities are added (A+B). Since  one ball is moving upward while other is using downward, using $$ R = |\vec{A} + \vec{B}| $$ makes more sense. Yet, answer comes wrong when I used this formula with 180 degrees. Any help on what to use or is my angle assumed is wrong or formula is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative velocity is the difference between the two velocity vectors. This is alwayas so, by definition if you want. It does not matter which way are the directions of the two vectors.
So, if you really want to use vectors, you just calculate the magnitude of the difference. The general formula for difference has a minus in front of the third term, no matter how the vectors are oriented. If the cosine happens to be negative, then the sign will change to positive (this is when the angle is larger than 90 degrees).
$$|\vec{A}-\vec{B}|^2=A^2+B^2-2AB\cos(\theta) $$
For $\theta =180^o$ this becomes
$$|\vec{A}-\vec{B}|^2=A^2+B^2+2AB=(A+B)^2  \ (*)$$
so, obviously
$$|\vec{A}-\vec{B}|^2=A+B $$
And this is the magnitude of the relative velocity which you use in the next step.There is no need to plug the numbers in equation (*) but even if you do, you get the same result as if you just add the magnitudes, of course.

Comment: So using $|\vec{A}+\vec{B}|$ was fault while angle being 180 was correct. Thanks

Comment: Btw do you think first formula to calculate magnitude is better than second formula. I saw some guys using absolute when finding R.

Comment: $R = |\vec{A} - \vec{B}|  = \sqrt{(A^2 + B^2 + 2A(-B)Cos\theta)}$ vs $R = |\vec{A} - \vec{B}|  = \sqrt{(|A^2| + |B^2| + 2|A||(-B)|Cos\theta)}$ Answer obviously wont match using latter but I wanted to know why absolute is used

Comment: Both formulas, for sum and difference, result from the cosine theorem. I am not sure what are you asking in your comment above. A and B here mean magnitudes.  So the vertical bars make no difference. A and |A|are the same thing. The minus sign is not because vector B has negative magnitude!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is way off, and you really don't need to use vectors for this.

First find the distance traveled by the first ball:

$$d_A(t) = a_At^2+v_At$$

then find the distance traveled by the second ball:

$$d_B(t) = a_Bt^2+v_Bt$$

You know that the two balls are pointed in opposite directions, so think about the signs of the accelerations $a$ and the velocities $v$ (i.e. does acceleration add to the velocity or work against it?).

Then once you get each distance, you can simply add them together.

What you were doing is trying  to find some kind of "average  or resultant velocity" for the two objects, which is not physically meaningful.

Also, in general rather than trying to find the correct formula for a physics problem, it's best to examine what is physically happening, especially by drawing diagrams, and determine the relationships between quantities (in this case, how does distance traveled related to starting velocity, acceleration, and time elapsed), until you find a way to compute what is needed from what is known.  No formula will work if it is applied incorrectly.

Comment: The question is from relative velocity and book also uses RV * t to calculate it. However, I have difficulty understanding why my initial solution is wrong or what potential solution is correct. Book does it directly Separation = RV*t = 30*3 = 90m without explanation

Comment: You can use relative velocity in this case because the acceleration due to gravity terms $at^2$ cancel, as gravity affects both objects in the same way, and you are only interested in the distance between them.  But you were trying to take the resultant velocity when what you need is the resultant displacement.  There are two separate objects.  If you combine their velocities into a "resultant velocity," no object actually possesses that velocity.